# Error 1 'MatankProj.DB.GeneralDB' does not implement interface member 'MatankProj.Entities.IEntity.PopulateStock(System.Data.DataRow)'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
public abstract class GeneralDB : IEntity
{
    protected DataTable table;
    protected int currentRow;
    protected string primaryKey;

    public GeneralDB(string tableName, string primaryKey)
    {
        DAL.GetInstance().AddTable(tableName);//bring data from database
        table = DAL.GetInstance().GetTable(tableName);
        this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
        if (IsEmpty())
            currentRow = -1;
        else
            currentRow = 0;
    }
    #region NAVIGATION
    /// <summary>
    /// going first line
    /// </summary>
    public void GoToFirst()
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
            throw new Exception("navigate on empty table");
        currentRow = 0;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// going to last line
    /// </summary>
    public void GoToLast()
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
            throw new Exception("navigate on empty table");
        currentRow = table.Rows.Count - 1;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// go next line if in the end go back to first
    /// </summary>
    public void MoveNext()
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
            throw new Exception("navigate on empty table");
        currentRow = (currentRow + 1) % table.Rows.Count;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// moves to the previous object. If reaches the beginning, goes back
    /// to the end
    /// </summary>
    public void MovePrev()
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
            throw new Exception("navigate on empty table");
        if (this.currentRow == 0)
            currentRow = table.Rows.Count - 1;
        else
            --currentRow;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// search obj by its key
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">the key being looked for</param>
    /// <returns>true if found and false if no such row  exists</returns>
    public bool Find(object key)
    {
        int r = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {
            if (dr[primaryKey].Equals(key))
            {
                currentRow = r;
                return true;
            }
            else
                r++;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// return current row
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Data Row of current row</returns>
    protected DataRow GetThisRow()
    {
        return table.Rows[currentRow];
    }
    #endregion
    #region GENERAL OPERATIONS
    /// <summary>
    /// return num of lines
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>number of rows</returns>
    public int Size()
    {
        return table.Rows.Count;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// check if table is empty
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns> true if empty, false if not empty</returns>
    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return table.Rows.Count == 0;
    }
    public virtual void Save()
    {
        DAL.GetInstance().Update(table.TableName);
    }
    #endregion
    public DataRow[] Filter(string filterString)
    {
        if (filterString.Trim().Length == 0)
            return table.Select();
        return table.Select(filterString);
    }
    #region CRUD
    public void Add(IEntity obj)
    {
        DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
        obj.Populate(dr);
        table.Rows.Add(dr);
        Find(dr[primaryKey]);
    }
    public void UpdateRow(IEntity obj)
    {
        DataRow dr = GetThisRow();
        obj.Populate(dr);
    }
    public void UpdateRowWithStock(IEntity obj)
    {
        obj.PopulateStock(table.Rows[currentRow]);
    }
    public virtual void DeleteCurrentRow()
    {
        string sqlString = "Delete from " + table.TableName + " where " + primaryKey + " = " + table.Rows[currentRow][primaryKey].ToString();
        DAL.GetInstance().ExecuteNonQuery(sqlString);
        MoveNext();
        object key = table.Rows[currentRow][primaryKey];
        MovePrev();
        table.Rows.Remove(GetThisRow());
        if (!Find(key))
            currentRow = -1;
    }
    #endregion
    public abstract object GetCurrentRow();
    public string GetNameType() { return table.TableName; }
    public abstract void Populate(DataRow dr);
}
}
```

I would like to know how to fix this error beacuse writing this isnt helping:
it tells me to add this public void populatestock(datarow dr) in generaldb and i dont understand what should i write in there....
it gives me an error in this line: `" throw new NotImplementedException(); "`
and its telling me that: `"The method or operation is not implemented."`

anyway can anyone help me dealing with this error:

```
" Error1 'MatankProj.DB.GeneralDB' does not implement interface  
  member'MatankProj.Entities.IEntity.PopulateStock(System.Data.DataRow)' "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should consult the documentantion of the Interface `MatankProj.Entities.IEntity`. There you should be able to gather information, what intention implementing `PopulateStock(System.Data.Row)` has. Second, you have talked about Visual Studio (I assume) giving you the error `throw new NotImplementedException();`. In fact, this is not an error. You seem to be trying to auto-implement the missing member by clicking something like *Implement members from IEntity*. Then Visual Studio always does something like this:

```
public void PopulateStock(System.Data.DataRow dataRow)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

...because VS wants you to replace `throw new NotImplementedException();` by your own code.

Since you said that it "is telling you" *The method or operation is not implemented.*, the method is executed at least once, hence you should take care of this. If you are able to find another implementation of `MatankProj.Entities.IEntity`, have a look at that implementation.

Comment: thank you for answaring me but after i sat down for cupel of hours in order to solve it i found the problem and fixed it .... and i didnt use:                                                      public void PopulateStock(System.Data.DataRow dataRow)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}                                                                     i did something which is like populate and mostly solved it so thanks anyway i really appreciate it tnx